# Remove self in lua

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm currently developing a game in Love2D and using an OOP library known as middleclass. Unfortunately, middleclass does not by default have destructors i.e something which allows me to destroy an object. I store all my objects in a table so I can loop through them and execute their Draw and Update functions. In my code I want the object to be able to remove itself. I have tried

```
self = nil
```

but this does not work! Would it be possible to find out the objects key in the table without looping through it to find it and then just use table.remove? This is still suboptimal as if there were references in the future i would have to remove it from those tables as well. 
How can this be achieved?

Comment: Usually, in object-oriented programming, you never explicitly delete an object (except for the purpose of freeing memory, in non-garbage-collected languages). What are you trying to accomplish by deleting the object? Do you want to delete it from the game world? If so, Love2D may have a "remove from the game world" function somewhere.

Comment: Why not using `table.remove` from the object itself? `function myclass:destructor() for k, v in ipairs(allObjects) do if v == self then table.remove(allObjects, k) self = nil return end end end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep your objects in a table indexed by the object itself: `cache[obj] = obj`. Then to remove the object from the game, you just need to do `cache[self] = nil` and (assuming there are no other references to that object) it will be garbage collected some time later.

If you have other places that reference that object, you may check if the use of ["weak" tables](https://www.lua.org/pil/17.html) is appropriate for your use case.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted. The weak referencing was perfect for my project!